# Keeping changes made on dynamic table in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular and I've been trying to make an editable Material table. I've followed a guide I found and have made sense out of most of it but I'm struggling to understand how to keep or 'save' the changes that are made once you edit fields in the table. At the moment once you click 'done', the fields revert to what they were previously. Am I supposed to try push the edits somehow into 'dataSource' when I click 'done', or something along those lines.

Currently this is how it looks

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="data">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" matColumnDef="{{column}}">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
        <span *ngIf="column !== 'edit'">
          {{ column }}
        </span>
      </mat-header-cell>

      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div *ngIf="!element.isEdit">
          <div class="btn-edit" *ngIf="column === 'edit'; spanHeader">
            <button (click)="element.isEdit = !element.isEdit">Edit</button>
          </div>

          <span #spanHeader>
            {{ element[column] }}
          </span>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="element.isEdit">
          <div class="btn-edit" *ngIf="column === 'edit'; else dataField">
            <button (click)="element.isEdit = !element.isEdit">Done</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <ng-template #dataField>
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>{{ column }}</mat-label>
            <input type="text" matInput value="{{element[column]}}"/>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-template>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `value` to set the value to the `input`, instead you should use `[(ngModel)]`, so it will update the value with two way data binding.

Update your code like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>{{ column }}</mat-label>
     <input type="text" matInput [(ngModel)]="element[column]">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Works! You're a life saver.